# When define a data as "[xxx]" , in what form should I use it in code?

Tags: haskell

Data definitions are as follow:

```
data SquareWorld = SquareWorld { theAnt :: Ant, theWorld :: [Cell]}
deriving Show

data Coord = Coord {xCoord :: XCoord, yCoord :: YCoord}
deriving (Show, Eq)

data Cell = Cell {cellPosition :: Coord, cellState :: CellState}
deriving (Show, Eq)

data Ant = Ant { antPosition :: Coord
           , antOrientation :: Direction
           , antTransition :: [Transition SquareTurn]}
deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I write:

```
changecolour :: SquareWorld -> SquareWorld 
changecolour squareWorld =
  let 
  old_cell = theWorld squareWorld
  old_cellstate = cellState old_cell
  new_cellstate =nextCellState old_cellstate 
  new_cell = old_cell { cellState = new_cellstate}
  newsquareWorld = squareWorld { theWorld = new_cell}
  in
  newsquareWorld

changedirection :: SquareWorld -> SquareWorld
changedirection squareWorld =
  let
  oldant = theAnt squareWorld
  old_cell = theWorld squareWorld
  old_cellstate = cellState old_cell
  olddirection = antOrientation oldant
  newant = case getStateColour old_cellstate of 
      1 -> oldant { antOrientation = succ' olddirection}
      0 -> oldant { antOrientation = pred' olddirection}
  newsquareWorld = squareWorld { theAnt = newant}
  in
  newsquareWorld
```

Error massage :

```
src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:152:31:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Cell’ with actual type ‘[Cell]’
In the first argument of ‘cellState’, namely ‘old_cell’
In the expression: cellState old_cell

src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:154:16:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Cell’ with actual type ‘[Cell]’
In the expression: old_cell
In the expression: old_cell {cellState = new_cellstate}

src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:155:47:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Cell]’ with actual type ‘Cell’
In the ‘theWorld’ field of a record
In the expression: squareWorld {theWorld = new_cell}

src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:164:31:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Cell’ with actual type ‘[Cell]’
In the first argument of ‘cellState’, namely ‘old_cell’
In the expression: cellState old_cell
```

It must be something wrong with my grammar but I have no idea about it.
Since type"Cell" is actually type[Cell], should I put"[]" in my code?

I am really confused about the meaning of "[]" in the data definition.

Comment: the `theWorld :: [Cell]` part? I tells you that the world consist of a *list of cells* ... the `[a]` is just a *list of `a`*

Comment: you should probably write `old_cells = theWorld squareWorld` and then `old_cellstates = map cellState old_cells`, ... - usually this is the point where *lenses*  come in but if you have trouble with lists I would not recommend poking into this ant-nest ^^ of a type-mess

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I should escape from this ant-nest now.